# Simplest fs.readFile example with generators and Q?

Tags: node.js, generator, promise, q

I've been using node's async as my standard flow control mechanism for years. It works, and I've never had to discuss or read about it since deciding to do so.

Apparently with generators and promises (of which Q seems to have acceptable documentation), I should be able to do:

```
var data = fs.readFile(somefile);
```

And have it handle exceptions. Which is nice. However all the documentation I've read on this is two thousand word treatises on the history of flow control, coroutines, thunking, nodeifying, etc.

**How may a simple, regular node std library call be made using ES6 generators and Q?**

Answer (score 0):

There are some simple examples at https://github.com/kriskowal/q/tree/HEAD/examples/async-generators. For your instance, it would look like this:

```
Q.spawn(function* () {
    …
    var data = yield Q.ninvoke(fs, "readFile", somefile);
    …
});
```

Comment: I'd like to have the var at the top scope. Is that possible?